# Flutter container inside a container

Tags: flutter

I'm practicing with flutter Container these days, and this example I came up with is simply astonishing

I put a Container of size 50x50 inside a Container of size 200x200. Strange is that the inner Container expand to 200x200 even though it has a tight constraint of 50x50.

Here's the code

```
Container(
  width: 200.0,
  height: 200.0,
  color: Colors.orange,
  child: Container(
    width: 50.0,
    height: 50.0,
    color: Colors.blue,
  ),
)
```

I expect a small blue box inside a bigger orange box.

Could someone explain why?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You need to specify where in the orange box you would like the blue box displayed, otherwise the blue box will grow to the size of its parent.

```
  Container(
    width: 200.0,
    height: 200.0,
    color: Colors.orange,
    alignment: Alignment.center, // where to position the child
    child: Container(
      width: 50.0,
      height: 50.0,
      color: Colors.blue,
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: It's almost 3 years later.  Having to still specify the alignment as shown to avoid the unexpected expansion of the inner container is still very non-intuitive.  Couldn't have the Flutter team specified a default Alignment such as Alignment.topLeft to then avoid such illogic?!

Answer (score 0):

In the code below we created a container that has a child called text and tried to style them a bit to make them look better.

```
Container(
  width: double.infinity,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.amber,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)
  ),
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
  child: const Text('orange juice is very delicious',
     textAlign: TextAlign.center,
     style: TextStyle(
       color: Colors.white,
       fontSize: 22,
       fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
     ),
  ),
),
```